# Which pairs to login into aws console?

Tags: amazon-web-services

IT send me these things:

```
auth-dev
user name
Access Key ID
Secret Access Key
Password
```

How to login to aws console please ? this is frustration, a very basic thing, i logged in with different combinations, keep on searching online, just no luck.

I know there's a term: key, secret. What is this secret access key ? cannot we have a unified name for the industry ?

Am i getting too old or what ? why these names are so confusing.

Comment: Are you speaking about this? https://aws.amazon.com/console/?nc1=h_ls In any event, why don't you ask them?

Comment: cannot find "Access Key“ in your page, it did mention username, password. But i still cannot login with that.

Comment: i cannot ask them since this is weekend :(

Comment: You can ask AWS support. The page I linked was not a tutorial, it was only to know if this was the resource you are trying to log in to.

Comment: well, my point is, this is a very basic question to aws dummy. Now i can easily search for javascript, python etc. questions online, but i cannot find the answer for this one easily, kind of disappointed. But thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To login to the web-based [AWS Management Console](https://aws.amazon.com/console/), use:

- Account ID or Account Alias (identifies your company account)
- Username
- Password

To make programmatic API calls, use:

- Access Key
- Secret Access Key

Answer (score 1):

Install the AWS CLI:

```
aws configure # answer the questions with info you have

aws sts get-caller-identity # find your user name and account ID

aws iam update-login-profile --user-name user-name --password secret
```

In a browser visit https://account-id.signin.aws.amazon.com/console